# How can i integrate Python scraping script with WordPress?

Tags: python, mysql, wordpress, apache, web-scraping

I want to scrape data using Python script and show data on WordPress site. Can I place Python script on Apache server with WordPress file?

> For example:

I have scraping file in Python (scraping.py).

I have WordPress site on server.

Then how can I get data on WordPress server from Python scraping file?
What is the best possible solution?

Comment: use php's `passthrough` function and call the `python` script with an argument.  `$output = passthru('python scraping.py $website_url');`

Comment: @Zak where will i place Python script ?

Comment: My WordPress website is live on server, so where and how can i place script? @Zak

Comment: You will need access to upload it to somewhere ..  FTP?  It's up to you at that point ..  If you can't get your script loaded onto the server, the point is moot.

Comment: The best solution is to rewrite it in php